# Openstack Neutron - Cannot Access Tenant Router Gateway

Tags: networking, juju, maas, openstack

Using cs:trusty/quantum-gateway-2, cs:trusty/nova-cloud-controller-40 and cs:trusty/nova-compute-2, while following Neutron setup as delineated in

- http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/install-guide/install/apt/content/neutron_initial-external-network.html/
- http://docs.openstack.org/trunk/install-guide/install/apt/content/neutron_initial-tenant-network.html

Cannot ping router's gateway. Actually, am able to ping it, only from Neutron node with namespace, i.e., ip netns exec qrouter-cddd34de-469e-4a69-90cf-07b3af242777 returns the pings. However, cannot do so from other nodes, with or without namespace. Also looking at Horizon's network page, status of External Gateway is Down.

Private network was designated as 192.168.1.0 and public network is shared with MAAS.Also noted that if "ext-port", in Neutron charm, is set to MAAS's physical interface, all connections to the node is lost. Any thought or help is appreciated.